# Understanding なんだか

Tags: meaning

If you look up なんだか in a dictionary it's translated as "for some reason" or "somehow" but sometimes it seems it's being used more in the sense of "kinda" or "somewhat". How exactly should I interpret it? Is it distinct from　なぜか in meaning? For instance, if a person says

> "**なんだか**嬉しい",

are they saying "I'm kinda happy" or "I feel happy, for some reason"? What about when a person says

> "**なんだか**とても嬉しい"?

Does なんだか indicate degree of intensity at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't interpret it "exactly" at all, because it conveys a sense of vagueness, a sense of not knowing quite why or how the current situation came about. It is indeed a conversational filler, and it looks as though you have understood it well. (If by "interpret" you mean "translate into English", then that is a whole different (big!) question -- translating the atmosphere of dialogue is very difficult.)